# PHP file uploads are limited in size despite php.ini edits

Tags: php, html, file-upload, upload

I have been trying for *weeks* to get a file upload system working in php. The code is fine and perfectly functional, but the uploads appear to be size-limited. They will crash out with chrome saying the connection was reset if any file is uploaded that is around 32mb in size. This isn't a code error as, when tested on another server, the limit is different.
I have tried editing php.ini's `max_upload_filesize`, `memory_limit`, `post_max_size`,`max_execution_time`, everything but to no avail (the changes are taking place, as phpinfo() reports). The server is IIS 8 if this helps. I have also changed the cgi timeout on IIS. How can I increase the upload size!?

Comment: Are you changing `max_post_size` or [`post_max_size`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIS allows upto 30 MB, so its failing to upload.
Please set post_max_size to more.
If still that is not working, in your IIS Manager goto "Request Filtering" and update Rule - Max allowed content length to the size you need.

Comment: Thanks so much! I've been tearing my hair out for weeks

Answer (score 0):

Search `post_max_size` and set `128M`

Comment: Sorry. I missed that out in my question as I didn't have the PHP.ini infront of me. I have changed that.